# Is it possible to have specific Bootstrap data-filter preselected when I get to that page by clicking the link?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, bootstrap-5, data-filtering

If I have buttons that filter specific items like on [this page](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/Eterna/) (on the portfolio page)

Is it possible to have a link that will lead me to that page but have specific filter preselected/pre-activated when I get there?

For example:
I have link on my homepage for "web" and when I click on it it directs me to that portfolio page and "web" category/filter is active, and so on for each category.

Comment: That's Isotope, yes it is possible using url hash filters. Working demo: https://cdpn.io/pen/debug/vErxXj#filter=numberGreaterThan50 Documentation: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#url-hash

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GrafiCode Took me a bit to make it work since I know 0 javascript but I got it working. Thank you.

Maybe add it as an answer so I can mark it as solved...

Comment: @LongLife if you solved it, self-answer your question, providing some code of course. I for one will upvote that